# Where is the location of the dependency?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

In the commons-validator/pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

But in the lib folder (tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib), only commons-beanutils-1.7.0 version is found. Where will be the jar file located for the 1.8.3 version and is it necessary that the given version of the dependency should be present?

Comment: Check in `~/.m2` directory.

Comment: checked in ~/.m2 directory, but the given dependency version of the jar is not present there.

Comment: Do you need both versions? If not then I think you should delete the previous version jar from `~/.m2` directory, do a `mvn clean install` again and then check what version jar got downloaded.

Comment: there is no  commons-beanutils  jar in the ~/.m2 directory

Comment: Try deleting your `~/.m2` directory and do a `mvn clean install`.

Comment: I am using gradle. And that jar flie is not located in ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1

Comment: this is such a confusing question. you have a web-app that you deploy to tomcat? and that application is using gradle that has a `build.gradle` that includes `commons-validator`? and there is something weird with versions? I am voting to close